# .htaccess mod_rewrite redirection not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using the following condition/rule on a .htaccess file located at the root of my domain. The purpose is to redirect all non-www requests to their www. version:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It seems to be working fine.

Inside my /blog/ subdirectory I have another .htaccess that I use to redirect fancy URLs to real ones:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !.*?url=.*
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

This also seems to be working fine. **However**, all non-www requests inside the /blog/ subdirectory are not being redirected to their www. version.

For example, if I type domain.com on the browser I correctly get redirected to www.domain.com. But if I type domain.com/blog/ or domain.com/blog/test-page/ I won't get redirected to the www. version.

Probably the .htaccess inside /blog/ is conflicting with the one at root level, but I don't know how or how to fix it. Any clues?

**Update**: I solved the problem by putting all the rules on the root .htaccess file. I had to tweak the fancy URL rules slightly to only catch the /blog/... requests. Here's the final .htaccess file in case it might help you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^apprush\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.apprush.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*?url=.*
RewriteRule blog/(.*) blog/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to put all of the rewrite rules into the root level `.htaccess`? It not only gets around the problem you're having but is a little neater because you know exactly where all of your rules are located.

If you are, these rules will do what you need:

```
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond ${THE_REQUEST} !/blog/.*?url=.*
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: Putting all the rules on the same file solved the issue indeed. I had to tweak them slightly, but it worked. I edited the post to contain my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have dollar sign `$` at the end of domain.com. Also you need to use `REQUEST_URI` instead of `HTTP_HOST`. Remove it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The dollar sign signifies the end of the string, thus making the rewrite to work for direct requests to domain.com. The update script solves the problem.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue (I tried and it didn't solve the problem). The HTTP_HOST will always end with the .com, as that variable is only the host and not the path. In fact my current script redirects correctly if I go to domain.com/contact/ for example.

Comment: Oh I haven't really noticed that. Updated with `REQUEST_URI`.